# Activity is creating again when i want to bring existing one to front

Tags: android, launchmode

I've added REORDER_TO_FRONT flag to bring my existing activity to top instead of creating a new instance. But it calls onCreate method of the activity instead of onNewIntent in MainActivity. If i add launchMode="singleTop" in Menifest, then works fine. But i don't want to add singleTop because in some cases in minimized mode if user click on app icon, then app restarts instead of resuming from same place.

```
    Intent intent = MainActivity.newIntent(context);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Usman Rana Do you want to finish the current activity and then show the previous activity or show the previous activity and hide the current activity?

Comment: i want to clear all activities including current and bring existing instance of MainActivity to front.

Comment: Check my answer, please accept if it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the SINGLE_TOP flag to your `Intent`, like this:

```
Intent intent = MainActivity.newIntent(context);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will remove all activities from the stack back to the existing instance of `MainActivity`. It will NOT create a new instance of `MainActivity` or call `onCreate()`. It will call `onNewIntent()` in `MainActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want close all other activities and start only main activity, this should work for you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this can help :)

Comment: I want to not start a new instance of MainActivity but bring existing instance to top to avoid call to onCreate method again

Answer (score 0):

No need of clearing the current activity and show the previous activity. Just use `finish()` method as shown below:

You can use this on your `onBackPressed()` and `toolbar` back button click:

Use this code outside `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish(); //closes current activity
}
```

On the `toolbar`:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         finish(); //close current activity
    }
});
```

The `onBackPressed()` method is called when the Android Back button is clicked. Its default value is `super.onBackPressed()` which also calls the `finish()` method! This example was just for reference.

The `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(...)` method is called when the toolbar back button is clicked. But for this you have to add these lines in the code in the `onCreate()` method:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The `finish()` method deletes the current activity from backstack and shows the previous activiy stored in the backstack!

Comment: I've a stack of activities these could be many. This is not a solution for that.